# Reopen a JInternalFrame on JDesktopPane/JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

I have a problem to reopen one JInternalFrame in my code. I select in MenuBar option "Cadastro"->"Cadastro de Veículos" and this action open one screen to insert a vehicle. However, if I close this screen and try reopen it again I can't anymore.

Below, two code that I'm using.

- First, JMain (that is my JFrame):

  ```
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;

  import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JMenu;
  import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
  import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
  import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
  import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener;

  public class JMain extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

      /**
       * Create the panel.
       */
      private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

      private JMenu firstMenu = new JMenu("Cadastro");
      private JMenu secndMenu = new JMenu("Indicadores");
      private JMenu thirdMenu = new JMenu("Agendamentos");
      private JMenu fourthMenu = new JMenu("Relatórios");

      private JMenuItem cadVeiculos = new JMenuItem("Cadastro de Veículos");
      private JMenuItem cadMotoristas = new JMenuItem("Cadastro de Motoristas");
      private JMenuItem cadCargas = new JMenuItem("Cadastro de Cargas");
      private JMenuItem newExit = new JMenuItem("Sair");

      public  JDesktopPane jdPane = new JDesktopPane();

      JCadVeiculos telaCadVeiculos;



      public static void main (String args []){
          JMain jmain = new JMain();
      }

      public JMain() {
          jdPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
          setTitle("Gtrix - Version 0.1");
          setSize(600, 500);

          getContentPane().add(jdPane);

          setJMenuBar(menuBar);

          menuBar.add(firstMenu);
          menuBar.add(secndMenu);
          menuBar.add(thirdMenu);
          menuBar.add(fourthMenu);

          firstMenu.add(cadVeiculos);
          firstMenu.add(cadMotoristas);
          firstMenu.add(cadCargas);
          firstMenu.addSeparator();
          firstMenu.add(newExit);

          cadVeiculos.addActionListener(this);

          setVisible(true);   
      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          if(evt.getSource() == cadVeiculos){
              if(telaCadVeiculos == null){
                  telaCadVeiculos = new JCadVeiculos(this);
              }

              //telaCadVeiculos.show();
              //telaCadVeiculos.setDefaultCloseOperation(JCadVeiculos.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
              jdPane.moveToFront(telaCadVeiculos);

          }
      }
  }
  ```

and JCadVeiculos (my JInternalFrame):

```
    package ui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Menu;

import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;

public class JCadVeiculos extends JInternalFrame {

    private JMain telaPrincipal;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public JCadVeiculos(JMain telaPrincipal) {
        super("", true, true, false);
        setSize(600,500);
        setTitle("Cadastro de Veículos");
        setVisible(true);

        this.telaPrincipal = telaPrincipal;
        telaPrincipal.jdPane.add(this);
    }

}
```

Please, help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the `JInternalFrame` visible again, as it was "hidden" when it was closed, for example...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getSource() == cadVeiculos){
        if(telaCadVeiculos == null){
            telaCadVeiculos = new JCadVeiculos(this);
        }

        if (!telaCadVeiculos.getParent().equals(jdPane)) {
            jdPane.add(telaCadVeiculos);
        }
        telaCadVeiculos.setVisible(true);

        //telaCadVeiculos.show();
        //telaCadVeiculos.setDefaultCloseOperation(JCadVeiculos.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        jdPane.moveToFront(telaCadVeiculos);

    }
}
```

On a personal note, I find...

```
 telaPrincipal.jdPane.add(this);
```

in you `JCadVeiculos` class worrying.  Your `JCadVeiculos` shouldn't really be making decisions about how it might be getting used and I'd personally refrain from making components publicly visible in this way, as it leads to possible misuse on the part of other developers.

The responsibility for the management of the `JDesktopPane` lies with the `JMain` class, it should be deciding what gets added to the `JDesktopPane` and when

Just saying.

You might also like to take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and make sure you're initialising your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: I really will read more about this link that you post, because I don't understand good what you explain me. If I find one solution, I will post here.

Thanks!

Comment: Really? I didn't think that the idea that when you close a , it's hidden (setVisible(false)), so you need to show it again (setVisible(true))